# PHP - Failed to open stream: No such file or directory (works on localhost, but not on webserver)

Tags: php

First of all, I know this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find a solution in the other topics.

My PHP Application is running with no issue on my localhost, but whenever I upload it to a Web Server, I get -

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

Using some of the answers found on Stack Overflow such as using `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to generate the following error:

`Warning:require_once(/home/users/web/b2365/nf.storyboardclubcom/public_html/beta/classes/Cookie.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hermes/bosnaweb04a/b2365/nf.storyboardclubcom/public_html/beta/core/init.php on line 28 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/users/web/b2365/nf.storyboardclubcom/public_html/beta/classes/Cookie.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php-5.5.22-amd64/lib/php') in /hermes/bosnaweb04a/b2365/nf.storyboardclubcom/public_html/beta/core/init.php on line 28`

Naturally I checked and I can confirm that these files exist in their respective folders on the server, and all permissions have been set correctly (755 on folders, and 644 on files).

Here is my code below for my initialization file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// Starting a session for users
session_start();

// Global Configuration
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
'mysql' => array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'db' => 'storyboardclub'
    ),

'remember' => array(
    'cookie_name' => 'hash',
    'cookie_expiry' => 604800
    ),

'session' => array(
    'session_name' => 'user',
    'token_name' => 'token'
    )
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/beta/classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  '/beta/functions/sanitize.php';

if(Cookie::exists(Config::get('remember/cookie_name')) && 
   !Session::exists(Config::get('session/session_name'))) {
    $hash = Cookie::get(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
    $hashCheck = DB::getInstance()->get('sessions', array('session_hash', '=', $hash));

    if($hashCheck->count()) {
        $user = new User($hashCheck->first()->session_user_id);
        $user->login();
    }
}
```

Any help on this matter would be much appreciated

Comment: check case also for file name. If sever is case sensitive then may be this issue occur .

Comment: Thank you, it was the solution I was looking for. Once the files have been re-named correctly, everything worked like a charm. Much appreciated.

Comment: Filenames are case sensitive on a unix  and not case sensitive on a windows box. Suggestion to developers is always use lowercase names for filenames, then you will never need to worry about this again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy Cookie.php file to the /home/users/web/b2365/nf.storyboardclubcom/public_html/beta/classes/ directory.

Comment: I can confirm that cookie.php does in fact exist under classes directory, with 644 permission.

Comment: File name is case sensitive. It should be exact Cookie.php, not cookie.php

Comment: Thank you, it was the solution I was looking for. Once the files have been re-named correctly, everything worked like a charm. Much appreciated.